# How do I install Xen without having a video system?

Tags: linux, networking, xen, hypervisor, headless

How can I install Xen on a system without having a video card nor onboard video?

Something about pxeboot or kickstart?

I've searched for the answer but keep ending up in docs that have very little to do with my use case.

I don't have optical drives in them. It would seem to require a solution involving creating a USB key to perform some kind of unattended install. After all, I can't interact with the installer..
Also, how am I supposed to configure UEFI over the network?

A bit more info:
There are 3 computers. I have a switch that needs setup. I have another computer running Arch and I can do the setup and create the USB from this one. Maybe host some install?

Waaaaaa.

Comment: Normally in these situations you have a serial console you can use to get a terminal on the machine, and you install and configure the machine that way. That's how it was done in the past, and how most network devices are still done. In the case of a modern server it requires that to be configured before the server goes headless.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Hmm.. I am thankful for your comment. Though it's not what I want to hear, it's useful to know.